# What is this audio datatype and how do I convert it to wav/l16?

Tags: python, html, audio, types, data-conversion

I am recording audio in a web browser and sending it to a flask backend. From there, I want to transcribe the audio using Watson Speech to Text. I cannot figure out what data format I'm receiving the audio and how to convert it to a format that works for watson.

I believe watson expects a bytestring like b'\x0c\xff\x0c\xffd. The data I receive from the browser looks like [ -4 -27 -34  -9   1  -8  -1   2  10 -28], which I can't directly convert to bytes because of the negative values (using bytes() gives me that error).

I'm really at a loss for what kind of conversion I need to be making here. Watson doesn't return any errors for any kind of data I throw at it just doesn't respond.

Comment: It seems like you'd want to convert those values to signed 2-byte/16-bit integers, then get the bytes representation of those.

Comment: Thank you so much that worked perfectly! If anyone comes across this, i just added `struct.pack('h'*len(data), *data)` and the content type was audio/l16.

Comment: You're welcome, I'll re-post my comment as an answer so you can accept it if you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those values should be fine, but you have to define how you want them stored before getting the bytes representation of them.

You'd simply want to convert those values to signed 2-byte/16-bit integers, then get the bytes representation of those.